# Python regular expression substitution function using lambda in the replacement field

Tags: python, lambda, substitution, python-re

I am trying to mimic `'i am your'.title()` string function with the following code to get the output as **I Am Your**.
But it gives the same ***i am your*** as output without capitalizing the words

```
re.sub(r"\b'\w", lambda m: m.group().upper(), 'i am your')
```

During the process of verfiying it, I came across this following snippet in the internet **but not able to comprehend how the lambda gets the input from/as**:

```
re.sub("[ab]", lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), "charly") # chArly
```

because,

```
>>> f = lambda x: x.group(0).upper()
>>> f("[ab]")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'

>>> f(["a","b"])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
```

To understand it better, I tried to decode it with Python disassembler, but still it seems vague

```
>>> dis.dis('re.sub("[ab]", lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), "charly")')
          0 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE 11877
          3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE 25205
          6 STORE_SLICE+0
          7 <34>
          8 DELETE_NAME     25185 (25185)
         11 FOR_ITER        11298 (to 11312)
         14 SLICE+2
         15 IMPORT_NAME     28001 (28001)
         18 DELETE_GLOBAL   24932 (24932)
         21 SLICE+2
         22 SETUP_LOOP       8250 (to 8275)
         25 SETUP_LOOP      26414 (to 26442)
         28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE 30063
         31 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP 12328
         34 STORE_SLICE+1
         35 <46>
         36 <117>           28784
         39 LOAD_NAME       10354 (10354)
         42 STORE_SLICE+1
         43 <44>
         44 SLICE+2
         45 <34>
         46 DUP_TOPX        24936
         49 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE 31084
         52 <34>
         53 STORE_SLICE+1
```

Comment: I would use regular *str* functions instead of regex: `' '.join(s[:1].upper() + s[1:] for s in 'i am your'.split())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to use `upper()` to get the first char in caps
- There is a `'` between word break and word escape literals, you need to remove that.
- And you need to use `m.group(0)` or `m[0]` to get matched string.

```py
>>> re.sub(r"\b\w",lambda m: m[0].upper(),"i am your")
'I Am Your'
```

Comment: Ah, silly mistakes! :) Thank you `Liju`. I replaced lower() to upper() in my original posting and left others as it is. Between, I noticed `m.group(0)` works in py2.7 and `m[0]` works in py3

Comment: `Liju` or anyone, can please explain how the lambda works in the 2nd code snippet of my post? I have made the question bold.

Comment: Because you have given `0` in `group()` which you didn't do in first snippet.

Comment: Suppose if I write lambda function this way, `f = lambda x: x.group(0).upper()` then how to pass the argument pattern and the source string to match the pattern with n this case?